# windows batch function cannot receive parameter value from caller

Tags: batch-file

here is the script sample, function `create_es_template` use `%~1` to receive parameter from caller. however, the result is always "template_name not set!". what is wrong in my usage?

```
:: create elasticsearch template

@echo off

:: define the function
:create_es_template
ECHO parameters: %*
IF "%~1"=="" (
  ECHO template_name not set!
  EXIT /B -1
)
SET "template_name=%~1"
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:: call the function
CALL :create_es_template  my_template_1
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

environment: Windows 10 Enterprise x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just move sub-function [:create_es_template] behind the main code. It will work fine.